# Nested variable reference inside eval() function in PHP

Tags: php, security

I'm trying to pass a variable that reference to another variable, into `eval()` function in PHP.

bin2hex and most of other PHP functions can't be used so I have to rely on (what I thought) PHP nature that parses hexadecimal into ascii string automatically.

When I tried to run this:

```
<?php
$t = "\x70\x68\x70\x69\x6e\x66\x6f\x28\x29"
eval($t . "();");
?>
```

the `phpinfo()` is called and displayed on the webpage

But when `$t` variable is referenced from superglobal variable like this:

```
<?php

// HTTP request:
// http://myserver.com/debug.php?t=$_GET['s']&s=\x70\x68\x70\x69\x6e\x66\x6f\x28\x29

// Info:
// $_GET['t'] = $_GET['s'];
// $_GET['s'] = \x70\x68\x70\x69\x6e\x66\x6f\x28\x29

eval($_GET['t'] . "();");

?>
```

the hexadecimal string is not parsed (printed as is instead) and not being executed.

My goal is to execute `phpinfo()` inside the `eval()` function  through HTTP query param ($_GET), since I passed `\x70\x68\x70\x69\x6e\x66\x6f\x28\x29` which is an hexadecimal for `phpinfo()`. But in my case, the hexadecimal is not parsed hence not being executed. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `"\x70\x68\x70\..."` only turns into `"phpinfo"` because you have written it in a PHP string literal. `$t` already contains `"phpinfo"`. `eval` has nothing to do with it. The string you get from `$_GET` actually contains the content "backslash ex seven zero ...", and that's not getting interpreted as a string literal (because it isn't a string literal). If anything, you'd need to create a string literal which you then `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `eval()` is not able to return the method results? Simply because you don't return anything in your eval part.
so do like this

```
$phpInfo = decode_code('\x70\x68\x70\x69\x6e\x66\x6f\x28\x29'); // here decode to string
eval('$phpinfoOut ='.$phpInfo.';'); // You can assign variable 
echo $phpinfoOut; // **TESTED IT WORKS** 
function decode_code($code){
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "@\\\(x)?([0-9a-f]{2,3})@",
        function($m){
            return chr($m[1]?hexdec($m[2]):octdec($m[2]));
        },
        $code
    );
}
```